# Android java - String length() issue

Tags: java, android, base64

I have a problem with base64 encoding of String values.
The returning strings are always 1 character longer than should be.
Maybe you know how to prevent Base64.encodeToString() from adding some additional characters to the output, thus spoiling it?

My issue code:

```
public static String encb64(String plain_str) {
        return  Base64.encodeToString(plain_str.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

---

Edited:
I did a test, and:

```
ShowMsg("ZG1pbjIzNDU=".length() );  // result 12  is OK
ShowMsg(encb64("dmin2345")length() ); //result 13 is NOT CORRECT (returned string is/should be: ZG1pbjIzNDU=)
```

Comment: Could you explain "1 character longer than should be"? What where you expecting? Could you give an example?

Comment: Additionally, note that calling `String.getBytes` without specifying an encoding is almost *always* a bad idea.

Comment: Overall though, I strongly suspect this is a problem of expectations rather than a flaw of `Base64.encodeToString` - but it's hard to tell without a concrete example.

Comment: Base 64 will not give the same length() after encoding

Comment: I added an example above. Actualy, I have hound that the Base64.DEFAULT flag adds some white characters to the end of the string. I solved it by changing the flag to Base64.NO_WRAP, or using String.trim(). Thank you All for interest.

Comment: @Priya: I know that. I was focusing only on the output string. When I was looking at it was 12 characters long but .length() returned it wrong.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: UTF8 is const and default. Dont worry about it there. And it is not low level programming or so.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's "low level programming" or not, I still firmly believe that explicitly using UTF-8 makes it clearer for everyone reading. Now you say the returned string is "ZG1pbjIzNDU="... the repro code you've given wouldn't even compile, suggesting it's not *actually* the code you ran. I suggest you assign the result of `encb64` to a string and then log various diagnostics on it: the length and then each character, as obtained via `charAt` and cast to `int`, to avoid any printability issues. I still think this is bound to be a diagnostic problem...